# Joining function taking longer than joining temp table with function data

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, function, join

So I have this scenario **in my function** where FooIds (function only containing ids) takes a while when joined than inserting it in a temp table:

```
SELECT TOP 5000 foo1.a, foo2.b, foo1.c
FROM fooA foo1 WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN fooB foo2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON (foo1.someId1 = foo2.someId1)
INNER JOIN fooIds(@user_id) i ON (i.id = foo1.someId2)
WHERE foo1.someStuff > @userInput
ORDER BY foo1.someId1 ASC
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
RETURN
```

This takes over an hour!!
However the following code takes 2 seconds:

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE (id int);    
INSERT INTO @ids
SELECT * FROM [FooIds](@user_id)

SELECT TOP 5000 foo1.a, foo2.b, foo1.c
FROM fooA foo1 WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN fooB foo2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON (foo1.someId1 = foo2.someId1)
INNER JOIN @ids i ON (i.id = foo1.someId2)
WHERE foo1.someStuff > @userInput
ORDER BY foo1.someId1 ASC
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
RETURN
```

I didn't want to create the extra declared table however this hack seems to be faster than the previous query. **Foo1** contains over billions of records, and **FooIds** over a few thousand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, avoid using multi-statement table function (and scalar functions with data access) in performance critical situations. Try inlining the code within the outer query instead.

Comment: But you can't use temp tables within a function, right?

Comment: Sure - I suggested to get rid of function entirely, didn't I?

Comment: Hmm, modified answer.. Anyway, I just read about inline functions vs multi-statement function, I'll give it a shot..! Thanks!

I'll mark you as the answer if it works

Comment: Great, it seems it is faster than the hacked multi-statement function.. ! Thanks a lot!